# Can we say that "C language operators are polymorphic"?

Tags: c

Can we say that "C language operators are polymorphic"  ?
For example if

```
int a, b;
float p, q;

a+b;
a+p;
p+q;
```

etc will generate different code when assembled, as the type conversion is needed the floating point coprocessor instruction needs to be executed to make the conversion and the floating point additions. So the operators operate differently depending on the objects they act upon.

Although these are implicit so if this can theoretically be called static polymorphism, operator overloading?

Comment: i believe that we *can* say that the operators in C (or other similar language) is polymorphic, wanted to know what actually they are considered. Because the polymorphism is demonstrated implicitly, and no user programming is allowed.

Comment: I agree. However, for the most part, polymorphism is only really useful if you can add to it, like in C++ where you can overload operators (and functions). In C it take a lot of effort to implement dynamic polymorphism, and a lot of macro hackery (and possibly a custom preprocessor) to implement any form of programmer-defined static polymorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we consider the operator `+` a function, then it matches the definition of a polymorphic function because it can "evaluate to or be applied to values of different types". So **yes**, it's a [polymorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) function.

Comment: operators are functions they perform a mathematical function or boolean function. Could we get refer some text defending the statement?

Comment: i knew it could be described theoretically as static polymorphism, but could not be sure enough to say them as they are polymorphic.

Comment: Mathematically speaking... However, there is no (built-in) C function that would return the sum of two arbitrary numerical variables. The behaviour of + is specified in the standard.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in theory this could be called static polymorphism or operator overloading. But since the polymorphism is fixed in its range of applicable types by the language definition, it's not a very interesting polymorphism.